# ubuntu drive not present bios after moving partition

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partition, windows

I have an SSD with two partitions one for ubuntu and the other one for windows, and, I don't know if this is important, but I also have a hard drive with two partitions to store windows and ubuntu data. Because I ran out of space, I got another SSD and I moved the ubuntu partition to this drive using Clonezilla, but after doing this, I can't boot windows or ubuntu, on the BIOS says "drive not present" for both OS.

I tried to fix this using boot-repair but it didn't work. I generated a Boot info summary using this tool and you [can find it here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Rb9CSxjtct).

I don't know what to do anymore, I hope someone can help me.

Update:
This is what I did to clone the partition with CloneZilla:

- Select device-device, then part_to_local_part, here I selected the ubuntu partition as the source and the new SSD as the target.

Finally, I selected skip checking/repairing source file system and that's it.

Comment: You cloned drive & left old drive connected. With true clone you cannot use old drive until you erase it or reformat it. You have duplicate UUIDs & GUIDS which are not allowed. And if booting, UEFI may go to one drive one time and other drive next time, getting them out of sync. Better to just do a total new install & restore from your normal backup.

Comment: Please elaborate what command you used for cloning, or what exactly you did in clonezilla.

Comment: @FelixJN I updated the question.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, probably something like that happened. What I end it up doing was clone the whole disk to the new one and it's working now but I would like to have ubuntu on one drive and windows on the other one, and not having two partitions like I do now

Comment: I do not know how to change UUID and GUIDs in Windows, probably embedded in BCD also. There are tools in Linux to change UUID & GUID, but then throughout system you have to update/change all those entries. Works if one or two data partitions, but a bootable install has many references to UUID. And UEFI boots using GUID or partUUID.  Often easier to just to new install.